# Django ManyToMany relationship avoid duplicates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have been thinking about this issue for two days and I cannot wrap my head around it.
So let say that I have a model called "Car" that has many to many relationships with my User model "Profile" meaning in my user model (Called Profile) I have:

```
cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars, related_name = 'profiles')
```

Now the car model has many to many relationships called likes so whenever a user likes a car it will be added to the likes of that car by:

```
car.likes.add(user)
```

Now my "Car" model will have 4 fields which are model, year, name, color
The issue is I want to query the database so that I can get the number of likes for all cars with certain models and years only. Meaning regardless of the name and color I want to get the number of likes.
Now I know I can get likes if all models with certain model and year  by writing:

```
def get_total_likes(self):
   Car.likes.through.objects.filter(car__model=self.model, car__year=self.year).count()
```

Now imagine a scenario where a user likes a car with model=A, year=1, color=r, name=something
and then they decide to like a car with model=A, year=1, color=b, name=somethingelse.

How can I NOT count duplicate users when getting the total number of likes? I mean How can I not count a user if they have already liked a car model with the same name and year?

I have written this method:

```
def is_liked(self,user):
      return Car.likes.through.objects.filter(car__model=self.model, car__year=self.year, profile_id=user.id).exists()
```

I have written this method for my template but how can I still make sure that when getting the total number of likes I won't count duplicate users? I am still confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

If your model definition is something like this:

```
class Car(...):
   likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)
   model = models.CharField(...)
   year = models.IntegerField(...)
```

You can try like this(using [**`distinct`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) in `Count`):

```
from django.db.models import F, Count

cars = Car.objects.annotate(
    like_count=Count(
        'likes', 
        filter=Q(
            model=F('model'),
            year=F('year')
        ),
        distinct=True
    )
)
print(cars.values('model', 'year', 'like_count'))
```

Comment: If I do not have the CarLike Model, will I still be able to use this or no it will not work?

Comment: yep, it will work without CarLike. Please see the updated answer